# Unity 3D leap motion

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, motion

I am currently working on a project and trying to get swipe gesture working. Current output is several instances of swipe gestures from just a swipe. How can i get one instance?

Thanks

Comment: What is your exact problem, what have you tried?

Comment: Gestures in the Leap Motion API are tied to individual fingers. So you will typically get multiple swipes from the same hand motion. You can ignore all but one.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (Input.touchCount > 0)
{
    Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
    {
        // One swipe gesture
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a Boolean variable to change state if a good swipe was performed and if it set to true, swipe recognition will be disable lets say 2 seconds or until some actions get completed.